# Using mysql_num_rows to display page numbers

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I am trying to use mysql_num_rows to then split the results of my query into pages (by dividing result by ten) but having trouble now writing the pages number front end script.

So I want it to look like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc

This will be based on:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$pageno = $num/10; // this will give the number of pages
```

So then I want to run the results so they dynamically populate with

```
<a href="page.php?page=$pageno">$pageno</a>
```

So essentially needs to automatically increment page number.

---

I used a combination of your answers and found this worked for me

```
for ($x=0; $x < $division; $x++) {
if($x=0){
$x=1;
}else{
}
echo "<div class='pageno'><a href='viewlist.php?page=$x&$stringVAR' >" . ($x+1) . "</a></div>"; 

}
```

Comment: Learn about sql's `COUNT(*)` to avoid fetching all rows just for counting them. Also learn about php's `floor/ceil/round` functions

Comment: this url my help you please visit it once   http://www.tyleringram.com/blog/basic-php-and-mysql-pagination-tutorial

Comment: I wouldnt use `mysql_num_rows` because thats going to make you actually grab all the data into a resultset which if the result set is large could take time. Instead use a count query first to get the total number of records, then use `SELECT ... LIMIT ?,?` to query records for a given page.

Comment: tahnks for this guys, was hoping i could use a quick $i++ type function to quickly increment the pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

biziclop is correct in suggesting that you should use a count of the number of rows rather than fetching all the records each time, but running a seperate query to get the count is innefective:

```
$rows_per_page=30;
$current_page=(integer)$_GET['page'];
$offset=$current_page*$rows_per_page

$qry="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as totrows, a.* FROM a_table LIMIT $offset,$rows_per_page";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     if (!$tot_rows) {
         $tot_rows=r['totrows'];
     }
     // show row data
     print....
}
print "Showing rows " . $offset . " to " . ($offset+$rows_per_page) . " of $tot_rows<br/>\n";
$pages = ceil($tot_rows / $rows_per_page);
for ($x=0; $x<$pages; $x++) {
  print "<a href='$url?page=$x'>" . ($x+1) . "</a>&nbsp;<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need the total pages

your `$pageno` are the total pages

you need a variable of page control:

```
$page=$_GET['page'];
if $page=="" then
   $page=1;
end if
```

then you need to split your sql result using LIMIT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/select.html)

> [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

your sql must be like:

```
$sql="select [..] from [...] where [...] LIMIT ".(10*$page-1).",".(10*$page)-1;
```

for `$page=1` -> LIMIT 0,9
for `$page=2` -> LIMIT 10,19
...

to put the 1  2   3  4  5 ...  now is easy

```
for($i=1;$i<=$pageno;$i++){
     echo "<a href=\"page_with_results.php?page=".$i·"\">".$i."</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows() function returns the no. of rows for the following query, $pageno=$num/10 just divides the no. of rows returned by 10.

for more info click http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_num_rows.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your Paging code goes like this:

```
    if($numrows!=0)
       {
           if($_REQUEST['rowsperpage'])
           {
                if(!isDigit($_REQUEST['rowsperpage']))
                    $rowsPerPage=10;
                else
                            $rowsPerPage =$_REQUEST['rowsperpage'];
           }
           else
           {
              $rowsPerPage =10;
           }
            $pageNum = 1;
            $mxpg=ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);
           if($_REQUEST['pageNum']=='undefined' || $_REQUEST['pageNum']=='' || $_REQUEST['pageNum']==0 || ($_REQUEST['pageNum']>$mxpg) )
            {
                $pageNum=1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(isDigit($_REQUEST['pageNum']))
                    $pageNum=$_REQUEST['pageNum'];
                else
                    $pageNum=1;
            }

            $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

            $sqlal = $SQL_QUERY." limit $offset,$rowsPerPage;";

            $resal=mysql_query($sqlal);
            if(db_num_rows($resal)==0 && $pageNum > 1)
            {
                    $pageNum = $pageNum - 1;
                    $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
                   $sqlal = $SQL_QUERY." limit $offset,$rowsPerPage;";
                    $resal=mysql_query($sqlal);
            }

            $maxpage=ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);
            $othrparameter="rowsperpage=$rowsPerPage&frmdate=$frmdate&todate=$todate&srchcity=$srchcity"; //serch criteria if any
            $tmpnavi=getnevigationhtml($pageNum,$maxpage,$file,$othrparameter);

            $onlynum='"Numbers"';

            $resultal = mysql_query($sqlal);
       }
```

Display on PHP form as below:

```
 <table width='100%'><tr>
<td align='left' >Rows  : <input type='text' name='rowsperpage' id='rowsperpage'  size='5' value='<?php echo $rowsPerPage;?>' onkeypress='return inputLimiter(event,<?php echo$onlynum;?>)' >&nbsp;
Go To Page: <input type='text' name='pageNum' id='pageNum' size='5' value='<?php echo $pageNum;?>' onkeypress='return inputLimiter(event,<?php echo$onlynum;?>)' >&nbsp;

<input type='submit' name='show' id='show' value='Show' >
</td>
<td align='left'><?php echo "Total :".$numrows;?></td>
<td align='right'><?php echo $tmpnavi; ?></td></tr></table>
```

Your record fetching will look like this :

```
if($numrows>0){
        while($res_image = mysql_fetch_array($resultal)){
//Your operations
}
}
```